# "Expected a Declaration" Building a C++ Linked List Homework

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, linked-list, declaration

Full disclosure: I am working on a linked list project for a course and my C++ is very rusty. I am trying to implement a function that we return the item found at a certain position in the Linked List. I plan on using this function in other parts of my code so it is essentially that it is error proof (stating the obvious).

I get the error "expected a declaration" and I can't find any apparent syntax mistake.

Your help and advice in general is greatly appreciated:

```
template<typename T>
T item_at(int position) const 
{
   SSLL<T>::Node* temp1;
   temp1 = new Node();
   temp1 = headNode;

    for(int i = 1; i < postion; ++i){

        if(temp1 == NULL){

        std::cout << "Invalid Position" << std::endl;
        break();
        }


       temp1 = temp1->next;

     }

// after the for loop the temp node will point at the node right before our desired position. 

return temp1->next;


}
```

Comment: For which line in the above code is the error given ?

Comment: The error wasn't from the compiler ( that is a scary bundle of errors atm ),  believe I have resolved the issue. I was returning a pointer rather then a T object.

Comment: Ok...so that didn't fix the issue. To be a little clearer, this error is being generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: Sure - same thing - but the error message contains a *line number*. Which line above is causing the error ? Please edit the question to include the full error message and indicate which line in your code it is referring to.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess it's the const statement.

const is used to prohibit changes to the internal state of a class.

In this case the function does not belong to any class which makes the const statement invalid and the compiler expects the method declaration instead of the const statement.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more detailed in my description of the problem ( its quite late over hear, forgive me ). The method is part of a class, but I have not posted it here as it is quite verbose and not yet in a completed state.

Comment: In this case you probably need the class name in front of the function name. E.g. MyClass::MyFunction(...)

Comment: Another thing: "break" is probably not supposed to be a function call (remove the brackets). Also please post the line number in which the error occurs.